# How to update a layer property for UIView and keep the layer for it subview?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, layer, subview

This is probably a beginners question about layers in iOS but I could not figure out a proper way to handle it...

I programatically create a UIView and add a button to it.

```
UIView *subview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)]; 
UIButton *mybutton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[mybutton setTitle:@"Test1" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
mybutton.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,50,50);
[subview mybutton];
```

Than I do some manipulation with a subview presentation changing it layer properties. For example I change a view border radius and add shadow:

```
[subview.layer setCornerRadius:10.0f];
[subview.layer setShadowColor:[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];
[subview.layer setShadowOpacity:0.8];
[subview.layer setShadowRadius:3.0];
```

The problem that I see these layer changes for mybutton also and not only for a subview.
For example a button title also have a shadow. 
I made a sample screenshot to better explain my question:
http://img46.imageshack.us/img46/8923/havq.png

How to deal with it in iOS? Is is a some kind of another layer that I add my button to?
Thank for your advices and help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't all of your changes to the layer, its just the shadow. That's because the shadow is applied to the layers composited alpha channel, and that includes its sub layers.

You could either:

1. Use a shadow path instead of the standard offset
2. Add a different sub layer on which to specify the shadow (where it is a sibling to the button)